# How Can I Loop Through URLs and import TD elements from several Links

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to import data from the following URLs, and write each data set to a CSV file.

Here are a few sample URls that I want to grab fundamental data from:
    https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=sbuc
    https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=msft
    https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl

How can I import the data from 'Index' to 'Change'?

[image]

I think the script should, basically, look like this.

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup("html.parser")

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
tckr = ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']
for stocks in tckr:
    url_list = [url_base + tckr]

with open('C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/today.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    for url in url_list:
        try:
            fpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage, 'html.parser')

            # write header row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

            # write body row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))            
        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
            print("{} - not found".format(url))
```

Except, when I run it, I get this error message: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: `url_list` `'AAPL'` is missing it's closing quote

Comment: Ah, yes.  I fixed that and one issue with the first loop.  I'm getting this error now:  TypeError: must be str, not list

Comment: That's because you are adding the list `tckr` to the string `url_base`.  You need to iterate through and pul out each value as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
tckr = ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']
url_list = [url_base + s for s in tckr]

with open('../Python/SOtest.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for url in url_list:
        try:
            fpage = requests.get(url)
            fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage.content, 'html.parser')

            # write header row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

            # write body row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))            
        except HTTPError:
            print("{} - not found".format(url))
```

I use requests so there is that difference.  But it works so you can pull code from there if need be.

Comment: Thanks jk622.  It looks like it is overwriting each previous record with each next record.  After the script runs, I see the numbers for AAPL, but not the other two stocks.  Isn't 'with open('../Python/SOtest.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:' supposed to handle that?

Comment: @ryguy72 Yes.  It should.  In fact, if you run it multiple times, you can see that it appends the data back to back.  I will have to debug.

Comment: @ryguy72 It had nothing to do with the `open()` call.  It was a hang up in the creation of our `url_list`.  I've changed it to a list comprehension.  It returns all three now.